# How do I stop unneeded Swift standard libraries from being shipped with my project?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I started an Xcode project (iOS app) as a mixed Objective-C and Swift project, but now I've decided that all I need is Objective-C. How do I convert it back to a regular Objective-C project?

I've removed all swift code and the bridging header, but the status bar still shows "Copying Swift standard libraries" when launching the app. I don't want extra stuff in my app that I don't need. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how to do it:

- Go to Xcode's project navigator.
- Click on your project.
- Click on **Build Settings**.
- Go to **Bridge Options**
- Set **Embedded Content Contains Swift Code** to **No**.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work. I already had that setting set to "No" and my Swift libraries are still getting copied over. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For me, disabling "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" (which was renamed to "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries") did not make any difference.

After hitting my head against the wall several times, I found the source of an issue. Disabling "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" is still needed, but apart from it I need to disable "Find Implicit Dependencies" option in the Build panel of my Scheme.